# Using Angular $first and $last outside of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show, ng-hide

I have this code:

```html
<main class="gallery">
    <nav class="gallery-list-thumbs">
        <ul>
            <li ng-click="showLarge($event); modalShow()" ng-repeat="photo in photos | filter:{'section': section }">
                <img data-ref="ref-{{ photo.id }}" data-orientation="{{ photo.orientation }}" class="photo-small" ng-src="photos/{{ photo.section }}/th/{{ photo.src }}">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <section class="gallery-item" ng-hide="modalHidden">
            <h1 ng-model="section">{{ section }}</h1>
            <div class="photo-container">
                <div class="modal-close" ng-click="modalShow()"></div>
                <div class="modal-prev"></div>
                <div class="modal-next"></div>
                <img data-photoref="ref-{{ photo.id }}" ng-repeat="photo in photos | filter:{'section': section }" class="photo-large below orientation-{{ photo.orientation }}" ng-class="{'above':$first}" ng-src="photos/{{ section }}/{{ photo.src }}">
            </div>
    </section>
</main>
```

What I hope to achieve, is to hide the `modal-prev` when the user click on the first `li` in `gallery-list-thumbs` and the same thing with `modal-next` on the last `li`.

So far, using $index, it's fairly easy since I can target it by a scope change, but how do I get the last element when there's a different amount of images per galleries?  It would be easier if the next and prev arrows were inside the ng-repeat since I could use `$first` and `$last`, but I don't want to have to include them in.

Comment: Can you provide a http://plnkr.co or http://jsfiddle.net link with working code?

Comment: Well, I have files all over the place and the backend is in MySQL, so it's not practical.. the closest thing I have is the site where it is now, with CSS working only on Tablet/Mobile breakpoints:
http://lexpostudio.com/galerie/architecture

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was able to find it by myself.

The solution was to change a scope on `$first` and `last` and then add a `ng-show` and `ng-hide` depending on the scope value.

Here's the code if anyone has this kind of issue:

```html
<main class="gallery">
    <nav class="gallery-list-thumbs">
        <ul>
            <li ng-click="showLarge($event); modalShow();setPosition('inbetween'); $first && setPosition('first') ; $last && setPosition('last')" ng-repeat="photo in photos | filter:{'section': section }">
                <img data-ref="ref-{{ photo.id }}" data-orientation="{{ photo.orientation }}" class="photo-small" ng-src="photos/{{ photo.section }}/th/{{ photo.src }}">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <section class="gallery-item" ng-hide="modalHidden">
            <h1 ng-model="section">{{ section }}</h1>
            <div class="photo-container">
                <div class="modal-close" ng-click="modalShow()"></div>
                <div class="modal-prev" ng-hide="currentOrder == 'first';">{{ currentOrder }}</div>
                <div class="modal-next" ng-hide="currentOrder == 'last';">{{ currentOrder }}</div>
                <img data-photoref="ref-{{ photo.id }}" ng-repeat="photo in photos | filter:{'section': section }" class="photo-large below orientation-{{ photo.orientation }}" ng-class="{'above':$first}" ng-src="photos/{{ section }}/{{ photo.src }}">
            </div>
    </section>
</main>
```